# Partition a number sequence in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have the following input:

```
(def nums [123456789012 123456789012])
```

I'd like the following output:

```
[[1234 5678 9012] [1234 5678 9012]]
```

*note both of these sequence contain numbers not strings...

I figured this would be really simple by doing the following:

1. Convert each entry into a String
2. Partition each string by 4
3. Convert each partition back into an integer

Here is my failed attempt:

```
(defn split-nums [nums factor]
  (map
    #(map
       (fn [x] (Integer/valueOf (str x)))
       (partition factor (str %)))
  nums))

(println (split-nums nums, 4))
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "clojure.lang.LazySeq@4834333c"
```

Which tells me I am dealing with a lazy sequence that I need to force evaluation on but when I try to (str (doall x)) I get the same result.

So clojure experts where am I going wrong?  Is this a good approach?  BTW.  I've just started to learn clojure so I'm certainly not an expert.

Comment: Also, I'm sure I will need to deal with possible leading zeros when I convert back to an integer but I don't think that will be too hard to fix :-)

Comment: Wow!  The stackoverflow clojure community is awesome.  Lots of good answers and I now see my silly mistake and some better ideas too.  I will upvote shortly after trying things out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defn split-nums [nums factor]
  (map #(map (fn [x] (Integer/valueOf (apply str x))) ; apply str
             (partition factor (str %)))
       nums))
```

---

`(str (lazy-seq [1])) ; "clojure.lang.LazySeq@20"`

`(apply str (lazy-seq [1])) ; "1"`

---

I'd probably write it to accept one number, then use `map`, instead of taking a coll.

```
(defn split-number [n factor]
  (->> (str n)
       (partition-all factor) ;; or partition
       (map (partial apply str))
       (map #(Integer/valueOf %))))
```

`(map #(split-number % 4) [12345678 12345678])`
`;; => ((1234 5678) (1234 5678))`

---

If you'd rather work with integers, rather than strings:

`(mod 5151 10)` `;; => 1`  Gets the least significant digit.

`(/ 5151 10)` `;; => 515` Removes the least significant digit.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out exactly where I went wrong - stringing together the sequence rather than stringing together each element in the sequence yielding a new string.  Also, I agree with your idea of making the method accept a single number.  I'm still used to other languages that have less powerful/concise ways of handling collections.

Finally, yeah probably better to just deal directly with the number rather than doing conversions.

Answer (score 7):

Why convert to String first? Here is a version with `/` and `mod`. This will also fix your leading zeros problem.

```
(defn int-partition [num size]
   (let [f (int (Math/pow 10 size))]
      (loop [n num l ()]
         (if (zero? n) 
            (vec l) 
            (recur (int (/ n f)) (conj l (mod n f)))))))

(defn split-nums [nums factor] (vec (map #(int-partition % factor) nums)))
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case I think for is really good to use. You don't have that many map.

```
(def nums [123456789012 123456789012])

(for [num nums] 
    (map #(Integer. (apply str %)) 
          (partition 4 (str num))))
;; => ((1234 5678 9012) (1234 5678 9012))
```

Comment: You have an extra closing paran - easy to do.  otherwise works fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
(def nums [123456789012 123456789012])

(defn part-int [l n] 
  (map #(Integer. (apply str %)) 
    (partition l (str n))))

(map (partial part-int 4) nums)
;; => ((1234 5678 9012) (1234 5678 9012))
```

Answer (score 2):

Slight variation of solution above by @nickik

```
(partition 3
  (map #(Integer. (apply str %))
       (partition 4 
         (apply concat (map str nums)))))
```

Comment: (apply concat (map ...)) = (mapcat ...)

Comment: Your solution is actually a little more flexible since you are doing two partitions so you could easily make the code produce [[1234 5678] [9012 1234] [5678 9012]] which wasn't one of my requirements but is still interesting.

Answer (score 2):

```
user=> (map #(->> % (str) (partition 4) (map (fn [s] (read-string (apply str s))))) nums)
((1234 5678 9012) (1234 5678 9012))
```

It's better to extract functions.

Comment: read-string is more than ten times slower than using Integer. or Integer/parseInt or Integer/valueOf etc.

Comment: Works but does have issues with leading zeros.  If the input was [123406789012 123406789012] it would fail.  Thanks for the alternate solution though.